# Expected an array of objects but got an object in an object

Tags: java, json, jersey, tomcat8

In a project I'm currently working on I got an angular exception: `Error: [$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration. Expected response to contain an array but got an object?`

In my search to find a solution I entered the URL of the web service directly into my browser and surprisingly I did not receive an array as expected.

The web service class:

```
@Path("/menu")
public class MenuHandler {
    @GET
    @Path("/cls")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Clazz> getCLSs()    {
        Clazz clazz = new Clazz();
        Clazz.setFoo("foo");
        Clazz.setBar("bar");

        ArrayList<Clazz> clazzes = new ArrayList<>();
        clazzes.add(clazz);

        return clazzes;
    }
}
```

When I enter the url `http://localhost:8080/myProject/rest/menu/cls` I would expect to see a JSON array with JSON objects:

```
[ {"foo": "foo", "bar": "bar"} ]
```

but instead, I receive an JSON object with a property the JSON object I was expecting without any array:

```
{
  "clazz": {
    "foo": "foo",
    "bar": "bar"
  }
}
```

So I wondered why there was no array and what would happen when I add another Clazz object. In that case I still get a JSON object but this time one of the parameters is the JSON array that I would expect to have from the start.

```
{
  "clazz": [
    {
      "foo": "foo",
      "bar": "bar"
    },
    {
      "foo": "foo2",
      "bar": "bar2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Can somebody explain me why this behavior is happening and where my thinking went wrong?

Comment: Please show what JSON provider you are using, all dependencies related to JSON, and any JSON configurations you have that might be of interest. This does seem to be a configuration problem. Either an explicit configuration or a default that is configurable (and may be fixed).

Comment: @peeskillet Both the javax.json-api and the jersey-json-1.17.1 jars are in the classpath of this project. Any idea how to find out which one is actually used?

Comment: I removed he javax.json-api and everything seems to work fine. This didn't resolve the issue, unfortunately.
In another project, the jersey-json is used as well and there everything works as expected. I tried to look for differences but I'm looking over it.

Comment: One way to see if jersey-json is being used is to create a `ContextResolver<ObjectMapper>`. Put a print statement in the `getContext`. jersey-json uses Jackson. If it's being used, the `getContext` method will be called. If it's not called, then it's not being used. In that case, you may want to try and trigger some exception on the serialization/deserialization to try and get a stacktrace from the serializer to see what serializer is actually being used.

Comment: Not really sure what you have in mind, so I made both an anonymous class inside the called method and a separate class of which I made a bean in the applicationContext.xml. Neither print statements was called.

But jersey seems to be used anyway
`at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider.writeList(JSONListElementProvider.java:145)
 at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractListElementProvider.writeTo(AbstractListElementProvider.java:264)
 at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:306)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.appl...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I spotted the problem. I was able to reproduce it. It seems you just forgot the enable the POJOMappingFeature

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

This uses Jackson to deserialize/serialize. If this is not set, it uses Jersey's internal JSON provider(s) to deserialize/serialize. I am not sure sure how to configure the default providers, but I think it's safer to just go with Jackson anyway.

---

Aside, in my comments above I was saying to test if Jackson is being used. One way to easily accomplish this is to just create a `ContextResolver` and and a s.o.p. inside the `getContext` method. This method is called when the mapper is needed. So if Jackson is being used, the s.o.p should print

```
@Provider
public class ObjectMapperContextResolver implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    private final ObjectMapper defaultMapper;

    public ObjectMapperContextResolver() {
        defaultMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
        System.out.println("--- getContext ---");
        return defaultMapper;
    }  
}
```

Note that this is also a way to make any configurations with the Jackson serization/deserialization (just configure the mapper).

Comment: Thank you!  It's not really clear to me yet what's going on, but I'll bookmark this one and come back to it when I've met my deadline :)

And as a bonus, this getContext method is indeed executed. The Json provider used is `org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider`

Comment: Yea I didn't realize that Jersey had it's own internal providers. Never really looked into the jar until I saw the stacktrace in your comments. So I guess my comment should have been _"to check if Jackson is being used"_, rather than _"to check if jersey-json is being used"_. We live and we learn :-)

Answer (score 0):

May be you want to use GenericEntity and return Response.

```
@GET
@Path("/cls")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public Response getCLSs() {
    List<Clazz> objects = new ArrayList<Clazz>();
     // logic goes here

     // now wrap List into GenericEntity 
    GenericEntity<List<Clazz>> entity = new GenericEntity<List<Clazz>>(
            objects) {
    };
    return Response.ok(entity).build();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for thinking with me. Unfortunately this didn't change the response I receive from the server