# I am seeing the error: A message body writer for Java class java.util.ArrayList, and Java type java.util.List<java.lang.String>

Tags: java, api, jersey

I am really new to **Java**, so I am am trying my hardest to learn. I am debugging someone else's code, and I'm running into understanding how to debug an issue.

I have the code:

```
protected List<String> getAllStringData(CRUDRequestWrapper user) {
    final WebResource resource = WsUtils.getLocalWebResource(session);

    List<String> response = resource.path("path/to/api")
                .entity(user, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                .post(new GenericType<List<String>>() { });
    return response; // This line IS NEVER reached
}
```

which enters and fires the API call to the code:

```
@POST
@Path("path/to/api")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public GenericEntity<List<String>> getAllStringDataApi(CRUDRequestWrapper wrapper) {    

    List<String> joinedFavorites = getAllStringDataAsList();
    return new GenericEntity<List<String>>(joinedFavorites) {}; // This line IS reached.

}
```

This API code executes and completes (as far as I can tell), *however*, upon return, I get a `500` and the debug information is printed to the console:

```
SEVERE: A message body writer for Java class java.util.ArrayList, and Java type java.util.List<java.lang.String>, and MIME media type application/json was not found
Aug 20, 2015 7:28:25 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse write
SEVERE: The registered message body writers compatible with the MIME media type are:
application/json ->
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONArrayProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONObjectProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$App
*/* ->
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.MimeMultipartProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StreamingOutputProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SourceWriter
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONArrayProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONObjectProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONWithPaddingProvider
  com.sun.jersey.server.impl.template.ViewableMessageBodyWriter
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JacksonProviderProxy
```

The problem is I have no idea what this means. I have seen a few other SO ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15618061/a-message-body-writer-for-java-class-java-util-arraylist-and-mime-media-type-t), in fact I implemented the `GenericType` that answer suggested) questions with the same error message, but none seem to give enough detail as to what I should be looking for.

**Does anyone have any idea how I can begin to debug this?** *It looks to me like the issue is after the API return, but before the calling function receives the list of string data*. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I see the JSON providers in the error message, so it seems you have the `jersey-json` dependency. But it seems (from what I tested) that the internal Jersey providers don't know how to handle lists of scalar values. For that you would need to make sure that Jackson is enabled. You can do that simply configuring the `POJOMappingFeature` in your web.xml

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Of if you are using a `ResourceConfig` subclass, you can do

```
public ResourceConfigSubclassConstructor() {
    getProperties().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING);
}
```

One thing to note is the way the internal Jersey providers handles JSON is a but different than how default Jackson handles it. For instance, Jersey will wrap the root value of the JSON (as [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32097870/2587435), which may not be desired), while Jackson by default will not.

If you are already used to the Jersey provider defaults and want to keep the format, then you will just need to tweak the Jackson configuration a bit. But usually the Jackson formatting is preferred over the Jersey formatting.