# My json missing [ ] for a list in Restful Api

Tags: java, json, api, rest, jersey

I was working on a restful api which should return a json data.

My service is like this:

```
@Path("tfs/projectRegStatus")
public class ProjectRegStatusService {      

    @GET
    @Path("/QA")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public ProjectRegStatusVO getProjectRegStatusQA(){
        return ProjectRegStatusModule.getInstance().getProjectRegResult("QA").produceNumber();
    }
```

And the entity ProjectRegStatusVO is like:

```
@XmlRootElement

public class ProjectRegStatusVO {
    private String name;
    private int colorValue;
    private List<ProjectRegStatusVO> children;
}
```

And my question is that when we only have one child, JSON Data should be like:

```
{
  "name": "SpecPool Risk",
  "colorValue": 48,
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "Hedge Sheet",
      "colorValue": 48
    }
  ]
}
```

But this is what I'm getting

```
{ 
  "name": "SpecPool Risk", 
  "colorValue": 48, 
  "children": { 
    "name": "Hedge Sheet", 
    "colorValue": 48 
  } 
}
```

This must have `[]` in child list, even if it only has one child.

But my result does not have `[]` in child list.

Could you guys help?

Comment: What JSON library are you using?

Comment: Your `children` element is a JSON Array already. What's the issue here?

Comment: `public class ProjectRegStatusVO {
 public ProjectRegStatusVO(){
  children = new ArrayList();
 }
 public ProjectRegStatusVO(String name, int colorValue){
  this.name = name;
  this.colorValue = colorValue;
  children = new ArrayList();
 }
 public ProjectRegStatusVO(String name, int colorValue,List<ProjectRegStatusVO> children){
  this.name = name;
  this.colorValue = colorValue;
  this.children = children;
 }
 public List<ProjectRegStatusVO> getChildren() {
  return children;
 }
 public void setChildren(List<ProjectRegStatusVO> children) {
  this.children = children;
 }`        Is this right?

Comment: i want this `{
  "name": "SpecPool Risk",
  "colorValue": 48,
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "Hedge Sheet",
      "colorValue": 48
    }
  ]
}` not `{
  "name": "SpecPool Risk",
  "colorValue": 48,
  "children": 
    {
      "name": "Hedge Sheet",
      "colorValue": 48
    }
}`

Comment: I just set media Type in my service like `import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;` and `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`, so that I could return a entity and it will turned to json. The second is fine,but front end need [] in evey children even if there only one in list.

Comment: It's possible the provider you are using is configured to treat single value arrays as objects. I've seen such cases. What JAX-RS implementation and and JSON provider are you using? Can you show your dependencies?

Comment: web.xml shows here `<servlet>
  <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>
   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
  </servlet-class>
  <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>package.webservice</param-value>
        </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>`

Comment: Please do not post updates in comments. Other than that, this is pretty much a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32115067/2587435). You need to configure the `POJOMappingFeature` to true

Comment: It is so kind of you to help, and since i am new here, i am learning how to ask question here. And your answer is right. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!. It's ok. Generally when you want to add new information, you can click the "edit" link under your post, then at the bottom type "Edit" or "Update" and add that new information below it. It's nearly impossible to try and read block of code in comments.

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
private List<ProjectRegStatusVO> children = new ArrayList<ProjectRegStatusVO>(); //Or Diamond Operator if using Java 7 and upward.
```

Alternatively, on your getter method, return an empty `List` if `children` is `null`.