# List of Objects returned as JSON object

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey

While developing a web service, I build a GET method to return a JSON list of System objects (a custom object, not the java.lang kind). Against expectations I receive a JSON object with 1 parameter containing the array that I initially expected. What am I missing here?

System Class

```
@XmlRootElement
public class System
{
    private long id;
    private String name;

    @XmlElement
    public long getId()
    {
       return id;
    }
    public void setId(long pId)
    {
       id = pId;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getName()
    {
       return name;
    }

    public void setName(String pName)
    {
       name = pName;
    }
}
```

REST service

```
@Path("/systems")
public class SystemHandler
{
   @GET
   @Path("/list")
   @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
   public List<System> getSystems(@Context SecurityContext sc)
   {
      List<System> list = null;
      //Populate the list
      return list;
   }
}
```

Result of /systems/list

```
{
    "system": [
        {
            "id": "248",
            "name": "FOO"
        },
        {
            "id": "617",
            "name": "BAR"
        }
    ]
}
```

While I was expecting

```
[
    {
        "id": "248",
        "name": "FOO"
    },
    {
        "id": "617",
        "name": "BAR"
    }
]
```

Comment: I don't know the source of the problem but its kind of wrapper JSON, i has the same in my case and you can chage the key `"system"` by doing `@XmlRootElement(name = "my_system")` for example.

Comment: Are you using Glassfish with Jersey?

Comment: @Maraboc Thanks for thinking with me. That does indeed change the key to "my_system", but it doesn't remove it. Neither does renaming the class

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin No I'm using Tomcat and javax.xml.bind.annontation annotations

Comment: What's your JAX-RS and JAXB implementations?

Comment: You mean the Rest service above?

Comment: @MichaëlBenjaminSaerens Yes, what are you using? Jersey, RESTEasy, Apache CXF?

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin I find some Jersey libraries in the maven dependencies, so I guess that one.

Comment: Didn't you [already ask this question ;-)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32097870/2587435)

Comment: @peeskillet I did... I go find myself a dark corner to hide and feel ashamed now :|

Any idea why on other REST services it worked fine? It was not the first one developed in this project

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `@XmlRootElement` annotation, this is telling Jackson to wrap the list in the system property and isn't required.

Comment: Removing it gives me the following error: SEVERE: A message body writer for Java class java.util.ArrayList, and Java type java.util.List<com.iba.smi.troubleshooting.system.System>, and MIME media type application/json was not found

Also, the XmlRootElement annotation works fine on other classes as well. Thanks for your thought.

Comment: Ah, in that case it sounds like Jackson (or something else being used to marshal java to json) isn't set up to map beans by default. As other comments have asked for, do you know what stack of technologies this is built with? Usually this would be marshalled without issue but looks like you need a bit more configuration.